# Endless permission on for another Linux user

Tags: centos7

I have a server with CentOS. I have there two web applications: the first one is a public application(with domain) and the second one is an admin panel for it(without domain).

Each application(public and admin) is difference Linux user.
So admin panel application can manage the public application through  DB and storage(remove/add files).

Now, I need to let the admin panel Linux user to manage public application storage.

What I do:

1. I created a group for these two Linux users(admin+publicApp) called GROUP
2. `chgrp -R GROUP /path/for/public/app`
3. `chmod -R 2775 /path/for/public/app`

After these actions adminApp can manage and "see" all files of public application. But it continues ~3 days. After 3 days adminApp cannot manage publicApp files again.

What is the problem and how make it endless?